# Need to drop value 'Select' from multiple columns from a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Have the value `'Select'` in various columns of a data frame. This value is as good as a `NaN` value, so the same needs to be dropped.

When checking the contents of a Column - Specialisation the following is what is displayed:

```
0                          Select
1                          Select
2         Business Administration
3           Media and Advertising
4                          Select
                  ...            
9235       IT Projects Management
9236        Media and Advertising
9237      Business Administration
9238    Human Resource Management
```

Similar value `'Select'` is available  in various columns which need to be dropped.

What code can be used?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with sample input, expected output, and _code_ for what you've already tried based on your own research. See [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) also

Answer (score 0):

If `"Select"` can be considered as `NaN` you can replace it by `pd.NA` everywhere and then drop it as you want by using [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'0': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
 'Select': {0: 'Select',
  1: 'Business Administration',
  2: 'Media and Advertising',
  3: 'Select'}})

df.replace("Select", pd.NA).dropna()
#       0  Select
# --  ---  -----------------------
# 1    2  Business Administration
# 2    3  Media and Advertising
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a bolean mask to only get the row which does not contains 'Select'.
The following code should work once adapted to your dataframe

```
df[df["name_of_the_column"] != 'Select']
```